# "Resource not found" displaying icon in AppleScript

Tags: macos, if-statement, applescript

I am new to apple scripting and I have a simple apple script which does below-

```
display dialog "Enter Your User Name:" default answer ""
set theUser to the text returned of the result
```

Now if the user enters nothing and clicks `OK` I do a check something like

```
if theUser = "" then
    display dialog "User name is mandatory" buttons {"OK"} with title "Missing parameter" with icon "stop"
    set theError to button returned of the result
    if theError is "OK" then quit
end if
```

But it gives me a `Resource wasn't found.` error popup when the `if` condition is checked. I have tries `theUser is in {"",value missing}`, `theUser is missing value` etc. but these don't work either. Whats wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop should not be in quotes. I assume that you want the script to stop executing when you send a "quit" command. You can accomplish this by adding a cancel button parameter.

```
display dialog "Enter Your User Name:" default answer ""
set theUser to the text returned of the result

if theUser = "" then
    display dialog "User name is mandatory" buttons {"OK"} default button {"OK"} cancel button {"OK"} with title "Missing parameter" with icon stop
end if
```

Comment: "stop" is just for showing the stop icon in the dialog box and nothing else.

Comment: Yes, and it should not be enclosed in quotes.